# How to get specific names from a binding List?

Tags: c#, winforms, mvvm

I have a binding list with streets. It includes a name and an ID. I want to show the names of the streets in a combobox. The thing is I only want street names to show with a specific start letter. Like my combobox should only show street names that start with the letter S.

If it helps, I use Windows forms and I try to use the Mvvm model.

Does anyone have the link for a solution? I got it to work that my combobox shows all the street names but not the specific names I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple program makes a list of streets and adds two streets to this list.
Then all streets starting with "S" are put into "streetsStartingWithS". This is done with LINQ. Then these streets are printed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;  

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Street> streets = new List<Street>();
        streets.Add(new Street("Superstreet", 1));
        streets.Add(new Street("Anotherstreet", 2));
        IEnumerable<Street> streetsStartingWithS = streets.Where(s => s.Name.StartsWith("S"));
        
        foreach (Street street in streetsStartingWithS){
            Console.WriteLine(street.Name);
        }
    }
}

public class Street{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Id {get;set;}
    
    public Street (string name, int id){
        Name = name;
        Id = id;
    }
}
```

Output:

`Superstreet`